# Get instance of class that relies on DI in Startup class

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I am running .NET Core 2.2 app and I have a bit of code that I want to run immediately after the initial setup in Startup.cs. The class relies on a registered type and I don't really understand how I am supposed to create an instance with the dependencies already injected. Let's say I have the following class that I want to run immediately after the setup is done.

```
public class RunAfterStartup
{
    private readonly IInjectedService _injectedService;

    public RunAfterStartup(IInjectedService injectedService)
    {
        _injectedService = injectedService;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _injectedService.Bar();
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can run `RunAfterStartup().Foo()` in Startup?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IInjectedService), typeof(InjectedService));
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    // I assume this has to go here, but could be anywhere
    var runAfterStartup = MagicallyGetInstance();
    runAfterStartup.Foo();
}
```

I know that in .NET Framework (not sure about Core) you could do this using SimpleInjector by doing something like `container.GetInstance<RunAfterStartup>().Foo()`, but I'm unsure how this works in .NET Core and I'd like to just use the built-in DI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First add `RunAfterStartup` to your services in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<RunAfterStartup>();
```

Now you can inject this class into the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, RunAfterStartup runAfterStartup)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    runAfterStartup.Foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the dependency injection container from the parameters passed:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    // I assume this has to go here, but could be anywhere
    var runAfterStartup = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IInjectedService>();
    runAfterStartup.Foo();
}
```

Comment: I think `IInjectedService` is supposed to be injected into `RunAfterStartup`, but I suppose it doesn't matter. Probably worth pointing out that this is basically the service locator pattern which is usually an anti-pattern, particularly when the framework already supports doing proper injection for you.

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me an instance of the `IInjectedService`? I would need that instance in the `RunAfterStartup`.

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry, copy/paste mistake. Just register your `RunAfterStartup` class and then use `GetService<RunAfterStartup>`